# Number theory: Unit group of ring of integer of number field

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Somebody can help me proof the unit group of ring of integer of 5th cyclotomic field is infinite

Comment: What is the inverse of $a+b \sqrt{5} \in \mathbb{Z}[ \sqrt{5}]$, when is it a unit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation

Answer (score 2):

Can you prove that $\Bbb Q(\zeta_5)$ contains $\Bbb Q(\sqrt5)$?

And can you prove that the integer ring of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt5)$ has infinitely
many units?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm reading " Number theory and fermat's last theory" (Ivan Stewart) and doing exercise 5 subsection 3.3 page 72. I can't solve it by the way that author gave! Can you show me more detail, sir!